# get object key value from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

hi i have one issue with get value from object if work fine before working with memored package in node.js  before i use data.driver.id and its get me it like 1010 but now it give me undefined

this is my object with all details

```js
var data = { event: 2,
  driver: '{"phonenumber":"123123","client":{"index":"103.104.34.250:59555","sock":{"_connecting":false,"_handle":{"fd":21,"writeQueueSize":0,"owner":"[Circular]","reading":true},"_readableState":{"highWaterMark":16384,"buffer":[],"length":0,"pipes":null,"pipesCount":0,"flowing":false,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":true,"calledRead":true,"sync":false,"needReadable":true,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"objectMode":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","ranOut":false,"awaitDrain":0,"readingMore":false,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":true,"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"_writableState":{"highWaterMark":16384,"objectMode":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"decodeStrings":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":0,"writing":false,"sync":false,"bufferProcessing":false,"writecb":null,"writelen":0,"buffer":[],"errorEmitted":false},"writable":true,"allowHalfOpen":false,"onend":null,"destroyed":false,"bytesRead":24,"_bytesDispatched":2,"_pendingData":null,"_pendingEncoding":"","server":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"_connections":1,"connections":1,"_handle":{"fd":17,"writeQueueSize":0,"owner":"[Circular]"},"_usingSlaves":false,"_slaves":[],"allowHalfOpen":false,"_connectionKey":"4:0.0.0.0:25001"},"_peername":{"address":"103.240.34.250","family":"IPv4","port":59555},"_consuming":true},"_actualLength":0,"_msg":[2,114,116,101,115,116,64,103,109,97,105,108,46,99,111,109,124,114,97,118,105,110,97],"_written":0,"driver":"[Circular]"},"online":true,"onDuty":true,"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"vehicle":"Sedan","id":1056,"fullname":"test01 test01","pendingRides":{},"ride":null,"rpm":"0","licensePlate":"dri123","logintime":1470925503}' }

console.log(data.driver.id);
```

i added my code so i want to get all property related to driver like id, fullname,logintime,latitude,longitude so please hele me with this error

Comment: data.driver is a string.

Comment: ... and you should parse the JSON string before reading the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON first. Try it like that:

```js
var data = { event: 2,
  driver: '{"phonenumber":"123123","client":{"index":"103.104.34.250:59555","sock":{"_connecting":false,"_handle":{"fd":21,"writeQueueSize":0,"owner":"[Circular]","reading":true},"_readableState":{"highWaterMark":16384,"buffer":[],"length":0,"pipes":null,"pipesCount":0,"flowing":false,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":true,"calledRead":true,"sync":false,"needReadable":true,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"objectMode":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","ranOut":false,"awaitDrain":0,"readingMore":false,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":true,"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"_writableState":{"highWaterMark":16384,"objectMode":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"decodeStrings":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":0,"writing":false,"sync":false,"bufferProcessing":false,"writecb":null,"writelen":0,"buffer":[],"errorEmitted":false},"writable":true,"allowHalfOpen":false,"onend":null,"destroyed":false,"bytesRead":24,"_bytesDispatched":2,"_pendingData":null,"_pendingEncoding":"","server":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"_connections":1,"connections":1,"_handle":{"fd":17,"writeQueueSize":0,"owner":"[Circular]"},"_usingSlaves":false,"_slaves":[],"allowHalfOpen":false,"_connectionKey":"4:0.0.0.0:25001"},"_peername":{"address":"103.240.34.250","family":"IPv4","port":59555},"_consuming":true},"_actualLength":0,"_msg":[2,114,116,101,115,116,64,103,109,97,105,108,46,99,111,109,124,114,97,118,105,110,97],"_written":0,"driver":"[Circular]"},"online":true,"onDuty":true,"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"vehicle":"Sedan","id":1056,"fullname":"test01 test01","pendingRides":{},"ride":null,"rpm":"0","licensePlate":"dri123","logintime":1470925503}' }

console.log(JSON.parse(data.driver).id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested parsing the string to convert it to an object. But it's already an object. Just remove the single quotes.

```js
var data = { event: 2,
  driver: {"phonenumber":"123123","client":{"index":"103.104.34.250:59555","sock":{"_connecting":false,"_handle":{"fd":21,"writeQueueSize":0,"owner":"[Circular]","reading":true},"_readableState":{"highWaterMark":16384,"buffer":[],"length":0,"pipes":null,"pipesCount":0,"flowing":false,"ended":false,"endEmitted":false,"reading":true,"calledRead":true,"sync":false,"needReadable":true,"emittedReadable":false,"readableListening":false,"objectMode":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","ranOut":false,"awaitDrain":0,"readingMore":false,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":true,"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"_writableState":{"highWaterMark":16384,"objectMode":false,"needDrain":false,"ending":false,"ended":false,"finished":false,"decodeStrings":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","length":0,"writing":false,"sync":false,"bufferProcessing":false,"writecb":null,"writelen":0,"buffer":[],"errorEmitted":false},"writable":true,"allowHalfOpen":false,"onend":null,"destroyed":false,"bytesRead":24,"_bytesDispatched":2,"_pendingData":null,"_pendingEncoding":"","server":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_maxListeners":10,"_connections":1,"connections":1,"_handle":{"fd":17,"writeQueueSize":0,"owner":"[Circular]"},"_usingSlaves":false,"_slaves":[],"allowHalfOpen":false,"_connectionKey":"4:0.0.0.0:25001"},"_peername":{"address":"103.240.34.250","family":"IPv4","port":59555},"_consuming":true},"_actualLength":0,"_msg":[2,114,116,101,115,116,64,103,109,97,105,108,46,99,111,109,124,114,97,118,105,110,97],"_written":0,"driver":"[Circular]"},"online":true,"onDuty":true,"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"vehicle":"Sedan","id":1056,"fullname":"test01 test01","pendingRides":{},"ride":null,"rpm":"0","licensePlate":"dri123","logintime":1470925503} }

console.log(data.driver.id);
```

Comment: how can i remove using code... if you have any code so please write here

Comment: @trusharwidetech You can't. If you don't have control over the original Javascript, just parse it.